# OutOfMemoryError using Akka Actors

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, akka, actor

I have an application that consume messages from RabbitMQ and i'm using Actors to handle the work.

Here is my approach:

```
object QueueConsumer extends Queue {

  def consumeMessages = {
    setupListener(buildChannel(resultsQueueName), resultsQueueName,
        resultsCallback)
  }

  private def setupListener(receivingChannel: Channel, queue: String, 
        f: (String) => Any) {
    Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
      Akka.system.actorOf(Props(new QueueActor(receivingChannel, queue, f))), "")
  }

}

class QueueActor(channel:Channel, queue:String, f:(String) => Any) extends Actor{

  def receive = {
    case _ => startReceiving
  }

  def startReceiving = {
    val consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel)
    channel.basicConsume(queue, false, consumer)
    while (true) {
      val delivery = consumer.nextDelivery()
      val msg = new String(delivery.getBody())
      context.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
    def receive = {
      case some: String => f(some)
    }
      })) ! msg
      channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope.getDeliveryTag, false)
    }
  }

}
```

After some seconds running, it throws a **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**.

I think that it's happening because i'm starting a new Actor for every message that i receive - so if i have 100000 messages, it'll create 100000 actors. Is it a good approach or should i implement something like an 'actors pool'?

Anyone have an idea how can i avoid OutOfMemoryError in my scenario?

Thank in advance.

edit1:

changed approach to:

```
class Queue2(json:String) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case x: String =>
      val envelope = MessageEnvelopeParser.toObject(x)
      val processor = ProcessQueueServiceFactory.getProcessResultsService()
      envelope.messages.foreach(message => processor.process(message))
  }

}

object Queue2 {
  def props(json: String): Props = Props(new Queue2(json))
}

class QueueActor(channel:Channel, queue:String) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case _ => startReceiving
  }

  def startReceiving = {
    val consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel)
    channel.basicConsume(queue, false, consumer)
    while (true) {
      val delivery = consumer.nextDelivery()
      val msg = new String(delivery.getBody())
      context.actorOf(Queue2.props(msg))
      channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope.getDeliveryTag, false)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating a new `Actor` for each message isn't necessarily bad design. That shouldn't make you run out of memory unless you're holding on to every reference of actor or message somehow so the GCer can't collect them.

Comment: @Samuel How can i check it? When the actor calls the callback (f), it does some queries on SQL Server (like INSERT / SELECT but are simple commands). Is necessary to implement something to 'kill' the Actor when callback is complete? I'm new using Actors.

Comment: It looks like Akka holds onto references of every actor you pass to `actorOf()`. So it seems like you shouldn't be creating a new actor for each queued message. I think you should have one actor for executing the SQL commands, and have your `QueueActor` read from the queue and send the commands to your SQL executor actor. Looks like you can use Akka.system.stop() to kill an actor reference if you really wanted to do what you're doing now.

Comment: @Samuel I've tried another approach but same error. Could you check this edition that i've did on the topic and check if it was what you were talking about?

Comment: Have you tried to put the nested `Actor` outside of `QueueActor` passing `f: (String => Any)` ass constructor argument? I seem to remember someone saying that it is a bad idea to expose one `Actor`s fields by closure to another `Actor`. Also (just a hunch), instead of blocking inside `receive` you could consider using a future to receive the message and create the message actor inside `Future.onSuccess`.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg are you talking about approach after or before edit? Do you mean put the nested Actor inside the callback function?

Comment: @placplacboom ah, sorry, the edit came while I was writing. No, your edit does exactly what I meant with *putting the nested actor outside `QueueActor`*. Did it help?

Comment: In your edited example, `Queue2` takes the `json` parameter as a constructor argument, and then waits for a message. You don't seem to either use the json parameter or send a message after doing context.actorOf?

Comment: @mattinbits you are right. I'm debugging it right now and it looks like that ''Queue2'' is never being called. The  code "context.actorOf(Queue2.props(msg))" is the correct way to start and execute a new actor?

Comment: Yes that's the right way to create the actor but it won't take any action once it's created, the way you currently have it. You either need to send it a message which is handled in `receive`, or override `preStart` and do the work in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your per-message actors will need to stop themselves when finished, otherwise they stay around forever. Please see the docs on [Actor lifecycle](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/scala/actors.html#Actor_Lifecycle) and [stopping Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/scala/actors.html#Stopping_actors). Here you’ll just need to add `context.stop(self)` after the processing is finished.